# Two divs: top - header with constant height and div-content

Tags: html, css

how can i get:

- div-Window which height can be random
- div-header with CONST height (30px)
- div-content that fills the rest of div-Window

sth like in the asci-sketch below:

```
+-divWindow------+
|+--divHeader---+|
||              ||
|+--------------+|
|+--divContent--+|
||              ||
||              ||
||              ||
||              ||
|+--------------+|
+----------------+
```

This is what i get so far:

```
#divWindow{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80px;right: 40px;
    width: 400px; height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#divHeader{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; */
    height: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: bottom;}
#divContent{
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

but divContent does not fill whole left space

Comment: You can achieve this with the `vh` unit in CSS. See following example :

    #divWindow {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    #divHeader {
      height: 30px;
    }
    #divContent {
      height: calc(100vh - 30px);
    }

Comment: If you use my flex answer from the duplicate, the footer is optional (before you say this is not a duplicate because that has a footer)

Comment: Here is an example using CSS `grid layout` -> http://jsfiddle.net/p1bjh76o/